# tablas categorias en mysql

Tags: mysql

Estoy montando una base de datos en mysql y quiero agregar tres tablas de categorías y subcategorías y otra de subsub categorías, rebuscando por el foro encontré unas tablas de ejemplo que me pueden servir para poder adaptarlas a mis necesidades queria copiarlas en la base de datos haciendo una consulta con sql para practicar pero al intentar insertarlas me da un error:

> (#1072 - La columna clave 'categoryId' no existe en la tabla).

No estoy muy segura del problema no se si alguien puede tener algo de tiempo para ver si hay errores, gracias.

```
create table categories 
(
categoryId int not null,
categoryName varchar(20) not null,
primary key(categoryId)
);

create table subcategories 
(
subcategoryId int not null,
subcategoryName varchar(20) not null,
parentId int not null, 
primary key(subcategoryId),
foreign key(categoryId) references categories(categoryId)
);


create tables items 
(
item_id int unsigned not null auto_increment,
name varchar(255) not null,
description varchar(100) not null,
primary key(item_id),
foreign key(categoryId) references categories(categoryId),
foreign key(subcategoryId) references subcategories(subcategoryId)
 )
```

Comment: Muestra tu consulta sql por favor

Comment: Hola Roger , en la pestaña de sql de localhost coloco el codigo pegado y me salta ese error , simplemente copio y pego ese código.

Comment: Hola. Con independencia de las ayudas que te hayan brindado. Considera **repensar** el tema, te basta con una sola tabla para manejar una estructura categorial, jerárquica, con el nivel de complejidad que desees.

Comment: Hola roger gracias ahora entiendo el problema que es lo que estaba pensando que estaba mal pero tenía dudas, de todas formas el tema de crear una sola tabla, o una estructura como esta me esta volviendo loca quiero crear tres categoria , subcategoria, y susubcategoria , entonces creo que debo crear otra tabla, quiero hacerlo de esta manera, por que me gustaría elegir después en listas desplegables cualquier subcategoría y creo que puede ser más fácil a la hora de ampliar categorias y hacer búsquedas más concretas ya que será para una app de anuncios.

Answer (score 0):

Estás creando mal la llave foránea ...
Se hace la foránea a la tabla referenciando a la otra.
Supongo que en la tercera tabla te o

```
create table subcategories 
(
subcategoryId int not null,
subcategoryName varchar(20) not null,
parentId int not null, 
primary key(subcategoryId),
foreign key(subcategoryId) references categories(categoryId)
);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estas agregando llaves foráneas a columnas que no existen, la solución es agregar una columna mas para usarla como llave foránea:

```
 create table categories 
(
categoryId int not null,
categoryName varchar(20) not null,
primary key(categoryId)
);

create table subcategories 
(
subcategoryId int not null,
subcategoryName varchar(20) not null, 
categoryId int not null,
primary key(subcategoryId),
foreign key(categoryId) references categories(categoryId)
);


create table items 
(
item_id int unsigned not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
name varchar(255) not null,
description varchar(100) not NULL,
categoryId int not NULL,
subcategoryId int not null,
primary key(item_id),
foreign key(categoryId) references categories(categoryId),
foreign key(subcategoryId) references subcategories(subcategoryId)
 )
```

otro arror adicional es la creacion de la tabla **items** se debe poner `create table` no tables

Comment: muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

El error deja claro que la columna no existe. El primer error se produce en la segunda sentencia al incluir el `foreign key`puesto que en esa tabla (subcategories) no existe el campo categoryId. En esta tabla debes poner la columna que se relaciona con la de cateroryId de la tabla categories. La puedes llamar igual, aunque sospecho que tu intención es que fuera la columna parentId, con lo que sería:

```
create table subcategories 
(
subcategoryId int not null,
subcategoryName varchar(20) not null,
parentId int not null, 
primary key(subcategoryId),
foreign key(parentId) references categories(categoryId)
);
```

Es decir, la columna parentID es la clave foránea de categories.categoryId

Debes seguir el mismo mecanismo para la tabla items.

Answer (score 0):

Hay 2 errores que son de `FK`, los ire documentando:

1. Tabla `subcategories`

- **Problema:** Estas referenciando una `FK` a un campo que no existe (`categoryId`)

```
foreign key(categoryId) references categories(categoryId)
```

- **Solucion:** Simplemente agrega ese campo si quieres unir las tablas

```
create table subcategories 
(
   subcategoryId int not null,
   subcategoryName varchar(20) not null,
   parentId int not null, 
   categoryId int not null, //Campo agregado para hacer la FK
   primary key(subcategoryId),
   foreign key(categoryId) references categories(categoryId)
);
```

2. Tabla `items`

- **Problema:** De igual modo que la tabla anterior, estas referenciando `FK` a "2" campos que no existen: `categoryId y subcategoryId`

```
foreign key(categoryId) references categories(categoryId),
foreign key(subcategoryId) references subcategories(subcategoryId)
```

- **Solucion:** Como en la anterior tabla, solo agrega esos campos y se solucionara

```
create table items 
(
   item_id int unsigned not null auto_increment,
   name varchar(255) not null,
   description varchar(100) not null,
   categoryId int not null,   //Campo agregado para hacer la FK
   subcategoryIdint not null, //Campo agregado para hacer la FK
   primary key(item_id),
   foreign key(categoryId) references categories(categoryId),
   foreign key(subcategoryId) references subcategories(subcategoryId)
)
```

Comment: muchas gracias voy a ver de solucionar.